# I have a problem breaking from switch statement in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

so I got this problem in my ReactJs sign-up component specifically in the switch statement, To simplify it the process contains 2 parts, when the first step is passed successfully the variable should change to the second step and start verifying its input but the problem is that the switch statement calls both cases every time regarding the variable i define can u please, so like if you notice the random console.log in the second case, it will be called eve if the first step did not pass, can you help me with this, Thank you in advance.

```
import { Google } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Hooping from "../../images/Hoopin.png";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { SignUp as signUserDataUp } from "../../reducers/userSlice";

function SignUp() {
  const userLoginInfo = useSelector((state) => state.user.loginInfo);
  const signUpForm = useRef("");
  const usernameForm = useRef("");
  const errMsgRef = useRef([]);
  let processPart = 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userLoginInfo?.isConnected == true) {
      navigate(`/user-${userLoginInfo.userId}/${userLoginInfo.username}`);
    }
  }, []);

  const [userSignUpInfo, setUserSignUpInfo] = useState({
    isConnected: false,
    userId: null,
    fullName: {
      firstName: "",
      familyName: "",
    },
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._]{8,16}$/;
  const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  const passwordRegex =
    /^(?=(?:[^!@#$%^&*()_+~-]*[!@#$%^&*()_+~-]){0,2})(?=(?:\D*\d){2,6}).{8,16}$/;
  const fullnameRegex = /^^(?=.{8,24}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+){0,3}$/;

  //  GENERATE ID

  function generateRandomString(length) {
    const charset =
      "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    let result = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length);
      result += charset.charAt(randomIndex);
    }
    return result;
  }

  const submitSignInInfo = (e) => {
    e?.preventDefault();
    errMsgRef.current.map((e) => {
      e.classList.add("hidden");
    });
    switch (processPart) {
      case 1:
        if (
          fullnameRegex.test(
            userSignUpInfo?.fullName?.firstName.trim() +
              " " +
              userSignUpInfo?.fullName?.familyName.trim()
          ) &&
          emailRegex.test(userSignUpInfo.email) &&
          passwordRegex.test(userSignUpInfo.password)
        ) {
          processPart = 2;
          signUpForm?.current.classList?.add("hidden");
          usernameForm?.current.classList?.remove("hidden");
        } else {
          if (
            fullnameRegex.test(
              userSignUpInfo?.fullName?.firstName.trim() +
                " " +
                userSignUpInfo?.fullName?.familyName.trim()
            ) == false
          ) {
            errMsgRef.current[0].classList?.remove("hidden");
          }
          if (emailRegex.test(userSignUpInfo?.email) == false) {
            errMsgRef.current[1].classList?.remove("hidden");
          }
          if (passwordRegex.test(userSignUpInfo?.password) == false) {
            errMsgRef.current[2].classList?.remove("hidden");
          }
        }
      case 2:
        console.log("jon jones");
        if (usernameRegex.test(userSignUpInfo.username) == true) {
          const randomUserId = generateRandomString(16);
          setUserSignUpInfo({
            ...userSignUpInfo,
            userId: randomUserId,
            isConnected: true,
          });
          dispatch(signUserDataUp(userSignUpInfo));
          navigate(`/user/${userSignUpInfo.userId}/${userSignUpInfo.username}`);
          errMsgRef.current[3].classList?.add("hidden");
        } else {
          errMsgRef.current[3].classList?.remove("hidden");
        }
      default:
        return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-auto min-h-screen bg-sign-up px-3 sm:px-9 md:flex md:justify-evenly md:items-center overflow-x-hidden">
      <img
        src={Hooping}
        loading="lazy"
        alt="HoopinLogo"
        className="hidden md:flex md:w-1/4"
      />
      <div className="relative block w-[92%] sm:w-3/4 md:w-1/2 lg:w-2/5 xl:w-2/6 h-auto min-h-[400px] rounded-xl border-4 border-black mx-auto md:mx-0 top-24 md:top-10 backdrop-blur-md text-center sm:px-2 py-4">
        <h1 className="text-primary-blue text-4xl font-bold">SignUp</h1>
        <form
          onSubmit={submitSignInInfo}
          className="relative w-full h-auto pt-6 pb-2 px-4 text-start"
        >
          <div className="w-full h-auto" ref={signUpForm}>
            <label
              htmlFor="fullname"
              className="text-xl xl:text-2xl ml-3 mr-80"
            >
              Fullname
            </label>
            <div className="w-full flex justify-between mt-1">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="fname"
                placeholder="first name"
                className="w-[48%] outline-none border rounded-md border-black h-8 sm:h-9 px-2"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserSignUpInfo({
                    ...userSignUpInfo,
                    fullName: {
                      ...userSignUpInfo?.fullName,
                      firstName: e.target.value,
                    },
                  });
                }}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                name="lname"
                placeholder="last name"
                className="w-[48%] outline-none border rounded-md border-black h-8 sm:h-9 px-2"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUserSignUpInfo({
                    ...userSignUpInfo,
                    fullName: {
                      ...userSignUpInfo?.fullName,
                      familyName: e.target.value,
                    },
                  });
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <p
              className="text-red-600 h-0 ml-3 hidden shake-appearing"
              ref={(e) => {
                errMsgRef.current[0] = e;
              }}
            >
              Please enter valid fullname
            </p>
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="email" className="text-xl xl:text-2xl ml-3">
              E-mail
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="email"
              placeholder="example@email.com"
              className="w-full mt-1 outline-none border rounded-md border-black h-8 sm:h-10 px-2"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUserSignUpInfo({
                  ...userSignUpInfo,
                  email: e.target.value,
                });
              }}
            />
            <p
              className="text-red-600 h-0 ml-3 hidden shake-appearing"
              ref={(e) => {
                errMsgRef.current[1] = e;
              }}
            >
              Please enter valid email
            </p>
            <div className="mt-6"></div>
            <label htmlFor="password" className="text-xl xl:text-2xl ml-3">
              Create password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="password"
              className="w-full mt-1 outline-none border rounded-md border-black h-8 sm:h-9 px-2"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUserSignUpInfo({
                  ...userSignUpInfo,
                  password: e.target.value,
                });
              }}
            />
            <p
              className="text-red-600 hidden shake-appearing ml-3"
              ref={(e) => {
                errMsgRef.current[2] = e;
              }}
            >
              Passwords should contain 8 to 16 characters with 2-6 numbers
            </p>
          </div>

          <div
            className="hidden relative w-full h-auto pt-6 pb-2 px-4 text-start appearing-left"
            ref={usernameForm}
          >
            <label htmlFor="username" className="text-xl xl:text-2xl ml-3">
              Create a username
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="username"
              placeholder="@username"
              className="w-full mt-2 outline-none border rounded-md border-black h-8 sm:h-10 px-2"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUserSignUpInfo({
                  ...userSignUpInfo,
                  username: e.target.value,
                });
              }}
            />
            <p
              className="text-red-600 hidden shake-appearing ml-3 my-2"
              ref={(e) => {
                errMsgRef.current[3] = e;
              }}
            >
              Username must be 8 to 16 characters and contain only letters,
              digits, periods, and underscores.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center mt-2">
            <h2>
              Already have an account?
              <Link
                to="/user-login"
                className="text-primary-blue underline ml-2"
              >
                Login
              </Link>
            </h2>
            <button
              formAction="submit"
              className="text-center py-2 bg-primary-blue w-3/5 rounded-md mt-3 text-3xl font-bold text-primary-white"
              onClick={() => {
                submitSignInInfo();
              }}
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <hr className="border-black border-[1.5px] mt-3 w-5/6 mx-auto" />
        <button className="text-center py-2 bg-[#4c8bf5] w-4/5 rounded-md mt-3 text-lg font-bold text-primary-white">
          Continue with google
          <Google className="ml-4 -mt-1" sx={{ fontSize: "160%" }} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SignUp;
```

Comment: You need `break;` statements at the end of each `case` clause.